# How to access boot disk as data disk in google compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have to been trying to follow steps mentioned in this https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/build-vm-image#create_a_licensed_vm_image guide to offer VM solution on google cloud marketplace.

With reference to step number 5 in the above link:-

The data disk shows up on my system with its boot and a data partition, but it is not mounted anywhere. I am able to access my installed application files on my current boot disk, which is weird since I did not install my application on this boot disk.

Here is my gcloud command for first instance.

```
gcloud compute instances create vm \
--image-family centos-7 \
--image-project centos-cloud \
--no-restart-on-failure \
--maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --preemptible
```

Here is my gcloud command for second instance.

```
gcloud compute instances create vm2 \
--image-family centos-7 \
--image-project centos-cloud \
--no-restart-on-failure \
--maintenance-policy=TERMINATE --preemptible \
--disk=name=vm,mode=rw,boot=no
```

Could someone please explain me step number 5 regarding boot disk cleanup in the link I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't catch what it doesn't work? You want to attach a boot disk to an instance, and to attach the same disk to another instance, as data disk? In the same time?

Comment: Accordingly to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/build-vm-image#create_a_licensed_vm_image) 5e "you will need to mount the data disk before you can access it. ". Please update your question with more details and explain "I am able to access my installed application files on my current boot disk, which is weird since I did not install my application on this boot disk."

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It seems that even though I am attaching the previous boot disk as data disk, the 2nd instance boots up with the previous boot disk (this behavior is random). lsblk outputs two identical boot disks. Now if i find my application running, then it means that I booted from the first boot disk otherwise the second. The only workaround I found for this issue is to spawn the 2nd instance first, wait for it to completely boot and then attach the previous boot disk as data disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach a boot disk as a data volume temporarily in order to fix it (VM cannot boot successfully from it anymore) then:

1. Create a new VM (**NVM**) with ssh access (add network tag `allow-ssh-iap`). **NVM** will start automatically (go for the least powerful and cheapest probably).
2. Stop the VM that uses boot disk that you want to fix (**BDYWF**) and detach the **BDYWF** disk from it (either via GCP UI VM->Edit or via `gcloud` command).
3. On GCP UI click EDIT on running **NVM** and attach **BDYWF**. Save config or use command `$ gcloud compute instances attach-disk <NVM-name> --disk BDYWF-name --zone=<NVM-zone>`. (*Attaching on-the-fly is done deliberately, because if bootable disk is attached to the VM while it's stopped or during the creation, there's a chance that VM will use this broken boot disk instead of real boot disk for this VM*)
4. SSH into **NVM**, activate super-user mode: `$ sudo su`
5. Check partitions with `$ lsblk` and take the one that belongs to **BDYWF** (e.g. sbd1).
6. Create mounting point: `$ mkdir /broken-boot-disk`
7. Mount **BDYWF** to mounting point `$ mount /dev/sdb1 /data`
8. Now you can access the data on **BDYWF** under `/broken-boot-disk` folder and fix it.